# Dynamically resize a form to fit the size of a Frame in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dynamic, resize, frame

I have an application that has 5 different sized frames. I'd like to dynamically re-size the main form to fit the frame when I move from one frame to another.

I can use the `MinHeight/MinWidth` properties of the frame to force the main form to fit the frame, but then when moving to a smaller frame, the main form does not adjust it's size.

Any ideas?

--Edit

```
...
TFormMain = Class(TForm)
...
public
  FrameImportPackage: TFrameImportPackage;
...

procedure TFormMain.MenuPackagesImportClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (Assigned(FrameImportPackage)) then
    begin
      FrameImportPackage := TFrameImportPackage.Create(Self);
      FrameImportPackage.LabelFrameCaption.Caption := 'Import or Edit a Package';
    end
  else
    begin
      FrameImportPackage.BringToFront;
    end;

  FrameImportPackage.Parent := Self;
end;
```

--Edit

Regards, Pieter

Comment: Is there only one frame visible at the time and you change the visible one depending on user input or some other condition? I'd say just set the size of the main form in the event / method where you "move from one frame to another" to the size of "current frame" ie `mainForm.Width := currentFrame.Constraints.MinWidth;`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to remove the confusion between panels (as in your question title) and frames.

Comment: Panel vs Frame is fairly irrelevant. The behavior is the same.

Comment: What does this do? `SetFrameParent(FrameImportPackage)`. Why not a simple `FrameImportPackage.Parent := Self` ?

Comment: That was redundant code. Removed.

Comment: If you're using `AutoSize` then the problem is not cause by the shown code; Take the time to test my code, I tested with both TPanel and TFrame, `AutoSize` works as expected. If you're NOT using `AutoSize`, you probably should, or at least show the code that manipulates the size of the parent window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you've got frames that don't change size, you want the form to update size to fit your frames. Let Delphi handle that for you, using the `AutoSize` property.

Set `AutoSize = True` for your form.

---

I've tested `AutoSize` with the following code, using `Delphi 2010`:

- Create a new VCL application. On the blank form drop a single Panel, let it keep it's name (`Panel1`). Make sure the panel is not too small, because we'll write code to decrease it's size at runtime.
- Set the form's `AutoSize` property to `True`.
- Drop two buttons on the panel, `Button1` and `Button2`.
- Double click the buttons, and copy-paste the following event handlers:

Code:

```
procedure TForm31.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var NewR: TRect;
begin
  NewR := Panel1.BoundsRect;
  Dec(NewR.Right, 32);
  Dec(NewR.Bottom, 32);

  Button1.Parent := Self;
  Button2.Parent := Self;

  Panel1.Free;
  Panel1 := TPanel.Create(Self);
  Panel1.BoundsRect := NewR;
  Panel1.Parent := Self;

  Button1.Parent := Panel1;
  Button2.Parent := Panel1;
end;

procedure TForm31.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Height := Panel1.Height - 32;
  Panel1.Width := Panel1.Width - 32;
end;
```

This essentially gives you two ways of decreasing the size of the panel, to handle two possible scenarios: `Button1` frees the old panel and creates a new, smaller panel. `Button2` directly resize the existing panel. Both work as expected!

Comment: I have done that and it works. The only problem is that it does not shrink when the current frame is smaller than the last.

Comment: I've just tested, the form automatically updates it's size just fine. I'll edit the answer to show you the code I'm using for testing. Maybe you should specify the version of Delphi you're using; Maybe even show the code you're using to show and hide your frames.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the code and we use Delphi XE.

Comment: Looking at your code, there will only be one frame and one frame only at any given time, and the frame is not replaced during the life of the application. It's a textbook example for `AutoSize`, should work without an issue. But make sure you *don't* have anything set for `MinWidth` and `MinHeight`, or else the form obviously can't resize.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Delphi 2006 there is a really anonying BUG with Form AutoSize.

You put a TStringGrid onto the form (Left and Top equal zero, align equal None, Top, CLient does not matter), when you change its ClientWidth and ClientHeightt the form not allways adjusts its size to the control.

Normally when it fails is when control size is reduced, form size does not get reduced.

There is no good fix, the only way to do it is manually set clientwidth and clientheight of the form when the object is resized.

It is said: Form AutoSize does not allways work well! It is a BUG on the VCL.